# "And" or "And in" with "in both"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Please help which one will fit in the blank and why?

1. The belief in life after death is prevalent in both primitive societies _________ advanced
   cultures.

A. and

B. and in

C. and also

D. also

E. also in

Comment: [What do you think? And why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am new to this community, sorry if i asked something not clear. I was confused between option A and B.

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters. Take your pick!

Comment: "And" with "in both" i think will be ok. Is that right ?

Comment: Simple "and" is more appropriate in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer on [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/44613-in-both-or-both-in/). They didn't provide the reason but the votes are for "And" with "in both"

Comment: This is more of a comment, since it just references an external source without explaining *why.*  Also, you spelt 'Grammarly' wrong!

Comment: It's the site name

Comment: not with an 'e'.  [gramm**a**rly.com](https://www.grammarly.com)